# crystal report shows blank unless zoom or page or refresh is clicked firefox only

Tags: firefox, crystal-reports

I have a crystal reports that runs fine until I tested it in firefox. It shows the data/report on first load but when I click "Go" button for report filter, it displays blank report unless I click any of these buttons - zoom in, zoom out, page/browser refresh and enter page no. This happens only in firefox. Chrome and IE load it just fine. By the way, I am using site.master page.

What I tried:

- suppressed report header
- unselect "new page" checkbox in report
- made sure in debug that report source has items in it. It has esp. when refreshed is clicked, it shows the report again. Also, I exported the blank report to excel and it does have data

What could be causing it? Any suggestion pls?

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
<asp:Panel ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
    <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="all" />
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td class="font_01">
                        From Date:&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvCalFrom" runat="server" ValidationGroup="all" >*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        <uc3:Calendar ID="calFrom" DateString="" runat="server" />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="font_01">
                        ToDate:&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvCalTo" runat="server" ValidationGroup="all">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        <uc3:Calendar ID="calTo" DateString="" runat="server" />

                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td class="font_01">
                        Unique Code:&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCode"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="font_01">
                        File Name:&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td >
                       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFileName"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="font_01" Text="Go" Width="50px"
                            Height="20px" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <!-- <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="font_01" Text="List All" Width="50px"
                            Height="20px" onclick="btnListAll_Click"  />-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="5" >

                  </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                <td>
                     <CR:CrystalReportViewer  Width="500px" Height="400px" ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

```
 public void loadReport()//(bool loadAll)
    {

         from = calFrom.DatePicked;
         to = calTo.DatePicked;
         uniqueCode = txtCode.Text;//Convert.ToString(Session["uniqueCode"]);
         fileName = txtFileName.Text;//Convert.ToString(Session["fileName"]);

      AirDataAccess ada = new AirDataAccess();
      List<AirData> alist=null;

      alist = ada.GetAllRawLogByFields(from, to, uniqueCode, fileName);


            ReportUrl = @"~\Reports\RawLogData.rpt";
            reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(ReportUrl));

           // reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.["MACCUserID"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MACCPwd"]);
            reportDocument.SetDataSource(alist);


            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;


            CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();


    }

    protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (reportDocument != null)
            {
                reportDocument.Close();
                reportDocument.Dispose();
                reportDocument = null;
                //Session["reportUrl"] = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {//handle error here
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
<asp:Panel ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server">

          <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="all" />
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td class="font_01">
                        From Date:&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvCalFrom" runat="server" ValidationGroup="all" >*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        <uc3:Calendar ID="calFrom" DateString="" runat="server" />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="font_01">
                        ToDate:&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvCalTo" runat="server" ValidationGroup="all">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        <uc3:Calendar ID="calTo" DateString="" runat="server" />

                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                    <td class="font_01">
                        Unique Code:&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCode"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="font_01">
                        File Name:&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td >
                       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFileName"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="font_01" Text="Go" Width="50px"
                            Height="20px" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <!-- <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="font_01" Text="List All" Width="50px"
                            Height="20px" onclick="btnListAll_Click"  />-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="5" >

                  </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnl" runat="server"  >
    <ContentTemplate>
                     <CR:CrystalReportViewer  Width="500px" Height="400px" ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Do the change like this and remove the code for unload........

Comment: Hi, I did what you suggested but still the same. I noticed the report blinks for a second (in which I can see the data report)after Go btn is clicked but still blanks out. :(. thanks

Comment: May I ask if the prob you had was specific with firefox only? My firefox version is 15.0.1. May I ask what was yours? thanks

Comment: I dont see it in crome but my problem was same.and my firefox version is 20.1

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="InventoryDocumentReportParameterCry.aspx.cs" Inherits="TexERP.ReportCrystal.InventoryDocumentReportParameterCry" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="RadFormDecorator1" runat="server" />

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddRecord" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="200px" Width="700px"
                Visible="true">
                <table width="100%" style="border: Solid 3px #005f9c; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr style="background-color: #005f9c">
                        <td colspan="4" style="height: 8%; color: White; font-weight: bold; font-size: larger"
                            align="center">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblReportHeading" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="text-align: right">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFrmDoc" runat="server" Text="From Document No:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDocumentNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvFromDocumentNo" Display="None"
                                ControlToValidate="txtFromDocumentNo" InitialValue="" ValidationGroup="FinalSave"
                                ErrorMessage="From Document No is Mandatory" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceFromDocumentNo" TargetControlID="rfvFromDocumentNo"
                                runat="server">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblToDoc" runat="server" Text="To Document No:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDocumentNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvToDocumentNo" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtToDocumentNo"
                                InitialValue="" ValidationGroup="FinalSave" ErrorMessage="To Document No is Mandatory"
                                ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceToDocumentNo" TargetControlID="rfvToDocumentNo"
                                runat="server">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="4">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Show Report" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                                ValidationGroup="FinalSave" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Reset" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                                OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlReport" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
             <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crvInventoryDocumentParameter" runat="server" 
                AutoDataBind="true" EnableParameterPrompt="false"
                EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="true"   HasToggleParameterPanelButton = "false" HasCrystalLogo ="False"
                 />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Use this code as a reference this is my code